# Getting error while connection MongoDB with Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
>   Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

And also MongoDB extension is not showing in phpinfo.

I have done:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Also install `jenssegers/mongodb`.

And add the MongoDB drive in `database.php` file and `.env` file

Comment: have you tried `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: yes i have tried that too